# Why is the slash character causing my selector to fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Using JQuery 1.6.4 on IE 11

I have an element with a slash in its ID.

```
<span id='a/b'>
test
</span>
```

In my code, I am doing

```
alert($('#a/b').length);
```

Output is 0. This only occurs when I have a slash (/) in the ID. document.getElementById('a/b') is functioning correctly.

So I am confused as to why the id with the slash is not working in JQuery?

Comment: Is it fixed if you escape the / character? \/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem with IE.

That is because `/` is a meta character and you cannot use it directly. You have to escape it while using.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

> To use any of the meta-characters (such as  ``` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^``{|}~ ```) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \.
>
> For example, an element with `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

Comment: Thank you for this information. If I may ask one other quick follow-up question: Are all of these characters operators in selectors? I see uses for several of them on w3schools here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp is the w3schools guide complete, or is there more to learn about selectors?