# DataTables export to csv with format Syntax error

Tags: datatables

I have datatables and I try to export it to CSV. The column 7 is a date.

```
text: 'Csv',
      extend: 'csvHtml5',
      filename: "customers",
      exportOptions: {
        columns: [1, 2, 7,8],
       format: {
          body: function (data, row, column, node) {
            //check if type is input using jquery
            console.log(data)
            return $(data).is("input") ? $(data).val() : data;
          }
        }
      }
```

It works all OK if I don't use "format" but with format I have error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 13/11/2021

When I log "data" without format, it is all OK. It looks like the slashes in date make problems in "format".
Any help:)

edit:
the date I take from firestore

```
let options = {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        day: 'numeric',
        //hour: 'numeric',
        // minute: 'numeric'
        // second: 'numeric'
      };
dataSet.push([
...
oc.data().created ? doc.data().created.toDate().toLocaleDateString("en-GB", options) : "",
...
```

Comment: Can you add the sample data which you are working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by your jQuery `$(data)` selector when the `data` variable contains one or more forward slashes. See:

- [Selector with string space and /; $(" /") throws uncaught error in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49642458/12567365)
- [Why is the slash character causing my selector to fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45199557/12567365)

And probably others.

A simple (but potentially error-prone) approach would be to write some logic like this:

```js
// possible, but not recommended:
data.startsWith('<input') ? $(data).val() : data
```

Instead of this type of approach, you can use DataTables' support for [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data).

In this new approach we will target the column which contains `<input>` fields, and specify two different versions of these data values for that column:

1. The version we want to display in the table (i.e. the actual input HTML).
2. The version we want to export (i.e. the value contained in the input field).

To do this we have to specify this for the relevant column (or columns). In my test example, this is the second column - so col index 1:

```
columnDefs: [
  { 
    targets: [1], 
    render: function (data, type, row) {
      return type === 'export' ? $(data).val() : data;
    }
  }
]
```

Here, I have specified that there will be a custom data type called `export` for the 2nd column - and its value will be the result of `$(data).val()` - and all other [built-in orthogonal data types](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) (`display`, `sort`, `filter`) will just use the raw `data` value.

Now I can use this new orthogonal data type in my export section of the DataTable:

```
exportOptions: {
  columns: [0, 1, 4, 5],
  orthogonal: 'export'
}
```

---

The overall solution using my test data is as follows:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="System Architect"></td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>13/11/2021</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="Accountant"></td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>14/12/2021</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="Dev/Ops"></td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>15/01/2022</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    columnDefs: [
      { 
        targets: [1], 
        render: function (data, type, row) {
          return type === 'export' ? $(data).val() : data;
        }
      }
    ],
    dom: 'Brftip',
    buttons: [ { 
      text: 'Csv',
      extend: 'csvHtml5',
      name: 'testExport',
      exportOptions: {
        columns: [0, 1, 4, 5],
        orthogonal: 'export'
      } 
    } ]
  } );

} );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The table looks like this:

[image]

And the exported CSV data is:

```
"Name","Position","Start date","Salary"
"Donna Snider","Dev/Ops","15/01/2022","$112,000"
"Garrett Winters","Accountant","14/12/2021","$170,750"
"Tiger Nixon","System Architect","13/11/2021","$320,800"
```

The benefit: I do not need any potentially error-prone logic to detect whether my strings contain `/` characters, or begin with `<input...` and so on.